# GKrellM vs. udev's asynchronous drive mappings on bootup

Tags: linux, udev, block-device

Well, supposing you had multiple drives (3 in this example), `udev` would always play dice with them on each system reboot. And now, let's make things a little more quirky by adding one USB flash drive you have connected.

So the setup may (or may not) look like this at system start:

`/dev/sda` HDD #1
`/dev/sdb` HDD #2
`/dev/sdc` Flash drive
`/dev/sdd` HDD #3

Since you're a clever "admin" of your own system, you've remembered to use *disk labels* in your `/etc/fstab` so you will not have to care about `/dev/sdX` assignments.

But `GKrellM` does not understand disk labels! That is, as far as I know.
So if you want to assign e. g. a command to *two specific drives* out of your three, how do you ensure that these commands are always executed on the drives you do want them executed onto?

Remember, on next reboot, HDD #3 might be on `/dev/sdb`, and your Flash drive on `/dev/sdd`. Totally random; as predictable as the lottery.

So does anyone know how to handle this issue?
(except for setting up hard `udev` rules in `/etc`, that is)

Comment: Why is setting up persistent udev rules not an option?

Comment: Because `udev` is designed to work asynchronously, hence I would only resort to this method if there is really no other way out.